# Specifying redirect_url when contacting salesforce rest api

Tags: rubygems, salesforce, omniauth

I'm trying to contact the salesforce api from my rails app. I use omniauth-salesforce gem for oauth. When I'm initializing the `OAuth2::Client`, my options hash looks like below

```
{ :site => 'https://login.salesforce.com',
:authorize_url => '/services/oauth2/authorize',
:token_url     => '/services/oauth2/token'
}
```

Now, since my redirect url is dynamic, I would like to add that to the options hash when contacting salesforce, so it can pick up this dynamic url and send the access token back to this URL. Please let me know how to add this.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the Force.com REST API toolkit. It contains the sample HTML Page which shows the way of passing the redirectURL. You can also see more details @ http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API